# Running a jar with depedency jar at a different java version

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

My project is running with java 7 while one of my dependency jar was built with java 8 according to its manifest file .I want to run my project in form of jar with dependencies at java 1.7 ! Is it possible to change to java version of the dependency  jar to lower version that is from 1.8 to 1.7 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It looks like a really bad idea.**

You will most likely encounter **[UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedClassVersionError.html)** :

> ### Class UnsupportedClassVersionError
>
> ```
> public class UnsupportedClassVersionError
> extends ClassFormatError
> ```
>
> Thrown when the Java Virtual Machine attempts to read a class file and
>   determines that the major and minor version numbers in the file are
>   not supported.

Comment: I have encountered that ! But my project is running on java 7 ! So what is the best way to make it run with java 7 ?

Comment: The best way to do that is to upgrade your project to Java 8.

Comment: I am downloading from dependency jar from maven through pom.xml ! Can I specify the java version of the jar to be downloaded there ?

Comment: No. You can only specify the `version` of the dependency you want to retrieve.